# Convert 16 bit color pallete index to 32 bit color

Tags: c#, colors, data-conversion, color-space

I have a file that contans 16 bit indicies for a "pallete". The "pallete" is not defined in the file. (The size of the image is known, that's not imporant though) I need to convert from an index (16 bit) to a 32 bit color (ARGB, 1 byte per channel). It would be nice to have
a little function like this:

```cs
Color GetColorFromIndex(short idx)
{
   return Color.FromArgb(...); // C#, but it doesn't matter that much.
}
```

(I know that because the index is 16 bit, number of all colors is 65536 (2^16) and that not *all* colors will be avaliable).

---

Also, a solution for any number of bits for an index (eg. 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1) that will make a 32 bit color would nice :)

Comment: 1. Are you sure it's a color index-based image and not just a 16-bit RGB image, e.g. R5G5B5 or R5G6B5? 2. If it is really a color index-based image you need to have a palette. Sure you could auto-generate one but this wouldn't really match the image in the sense that all colors would be off. Color indexes are often not continuous and where often chosen based on what colors where used in the image most, i.e. can be heavily dependent on the specific image.

Comment: No, indices are stored in the image. I am generating the image really... :) But I don't want to have a pallete *in* the image file because I do not have any sort of compression and the image size is very big because of that. So I chose not 32 bit colors but smaller indices. Because then you can change the pallete generation and the image colors would be different (that can also be useful).